# What could cause a program to be less accurate in C than in matlab?

Tags: c, matlab, floating-accuracy, double-precision

I wrote an orbit propagator (calculates position and velocity of a satellite for each time step) in matlab and it's pretty accurate (4.5 km in a 24-hour propagation). I had to rewrite it in C, I did it and it's working properly but my results are much less accurate (450 km for a 24-hour propagation), so I was wondering what could cause this loss of accuracy in C for the exact same calculations (I compared the scripts to be sure I didn't forget anything.) ?

All my variables are double or long double depending on the needs. There are no divisions by ints. The error grows linearly over time.

My main function contains a while loop that updates the values of my position and velocity arrays by calling the calculating function that takes pointers to the arrays as arguments.

Comment: some code would be nice

Comment: Start by reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Can you identify a particular calculation that causes the divergence in behaviour?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It should not be necessary to read that in order to translate some Matlab code to C ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Probably not, but it might be to understand problems with floating point arithmetic. :)

Comment: **Don't** start by reading the reference provided by @JoachimPileborg.  If you do need a primer on floating-point arithmetic start at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point.  Goldberg's paper is addressed to designers of f-p systems, not users.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how big are your time steps?  Do you get as big a divergence if you use coarser or finer steps?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without code, best advice  would be to dump all intermediate computations to files (both in matlab and C) and then compare them to find where divergence is occurring.